# Error with mongodb driver on Heroku: Cannot find module 'mongodb-core'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I'm trying to upgrade my Node.js Express app to a newer driver for Mongodb.  My package.json has "mongodb": "^2.0.40".  It runs fine on my machine, and I'm able to deploy to Heroku fine (as in, no warning/errors). However, the app crashes upon use, with this error:

```
2015-09-14T13:03:52.225525+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2015-09-14T13:03:52.271972+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2015-09-14T13:03:54.315461+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2015-09-14T13:03:54.701499+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:338
2015-09-14T13:03:54.701522+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2015-09-14T13:03:54.701523+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2015-09-14T13:03:54.701525+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb-core'
2015-09-14T13:03:54.701526+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
2015-09-14T13:03:54.701527+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
2015-09-14T13:03:54.701529+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:384:17)
2015-09-14T13:03:54.701528+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
2015-09-14T13:03:54.701531+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb/index.js:2:12)
2015-09-14T13:03:54.701532+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
2015-09-14T13:03:54.701533+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
2015-09-14T13:03:54.701534+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
2015-09-14T13:03:54.701535+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
2015-09-14T13:03:54.701536+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
2015-09-14T13:03:55.561071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2015-09-14T13:03:55.548974+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

I've tried various versions of mongodb driver, to no avail.

Comment: would you mind populating package.json "dependencies" section? and "remote: -----> Build succeeded!" from output?..

Answer (score 0):

if you use mongodb-core, you should specify it in package.json like here:

```
   "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.9.x"
    , "pg": "~4.4.x"
    , "mongodb": "2.0.14"
    , "mongodb-core": "~1.0"
  },
```

after pushing it to git, check the log:

```
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote:        ├── express@4.9.8
remote:        ├── mongodb@2.0.14
remote:        ├── mongodb-core@1.0.5
remote:        └── pg@4.4.1
```